# Word describing How a person is being when using an adjective in a statement that is based on opinion rather than fact

Tags: adjectives

An example would be:

“The White House is really tall”
When it’s actually not but to one person accustomed to 1 story buildings would feel that it is tall.

Or

“You are a bad driver” 
Being based again on perspective, yet also objective in a way.

The only other way I can describe the word I’m looking for is to say that other people can have differing descriptions of the same thing and all be right in their own way, but no one being scientifically or technically correct.

Like... “this is redder than that” could be replaced with “this is 2 shades redder than that”

... if one person heard (the listener) sentence #1 in this last example, the listener would be able to respond.. **”you are being ___”**

This is the only way I can think to put the word in use to aid in identifying the word itself. There may be a few words that fit this description but one is PERFECTLY fit for these examples, I really hope to find the word.

My coworkers use a lot of opinion in their descriptions in a very technical field so this would help to teach them how to be more accurate for a lack of better words.

Thanks in advanced!

(The word I hunt is not used in this of course, and may end in “__ive” like “perspective” but that word doesn’t fit description I have and it doesn’t make sense as far as proper sentence structure or grammar goes. Something like... objective.. but not quite it. Like a biased description being identified as biased.. i don’t know..)

Comment: They are _subjective_.

Comment: This guy got it I think, but I got a feeling it’s not quite the word but it’s so similar

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for the term _relative subsectiveness_ 
 (though what you describe above seems a closer fit with 'subjectiveness', ie dependence on an individual's judgement [calls] {or, in other cases, preferences}). However, the term I'm offering covers situations which occur in English, where _everyone would agree_ for instance that Suilven is a small mountain but Queen Alexandra's birdwing is a large butterfly. See [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104700/term-for-things-like-naughty-step-where-the-step-is-not-what-is-naughty/238880#238880).

Comment: Relative!!!!! Thank you!!!!